# MySQL skips inserting records to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am getting an issue with `MySQL` or `PHP`; I am not sure. But, the issue is `PHP` query has been skipping the insertion of some records to the `MySQL` table. There are no entries for some records while the code seems fine when tested.

I have been using this query to insert records into the database. Also, I am creating a string of queries and executing `multi_query` at some other place. While the string looks good and has been inserting records too. It's just some of the records that it skips.

```
INSERT INTO donations_detail (orderid, piece, amount, project_name, other, project_pay_name, dtype, project_code, project_sub_code) VALUES ('".$payid."', '".$piece."', '".$amount."', '".$row2["project_name"]."', '".$row["other"]."', '".$project_pay_name."', '".$row["dtype"]."', '".$row2["project_code"]."', '".$project_sub_code."');
```

Comment: show your code?  are you checking for errors?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO donations_detail (orderid, piece, amount, project_name, other, project_pay_name, dtype, project_code, project_sub_code) VALUES ('$payid', '$piece', '$amount', '".$row2['project_name']."', '".$row['other']."', '".$project_pay_name."', '".$row['dtype']."', '".$row2['project_code']."', '$project_sub_code');`

Comment: Sorry, but what are the differences? @Hritik R